# Progress Bar Not Updating Xamarin Forms MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I know this has been asked before but I've spent ages and nothing has helped.

I'm trying to update a progress bar from a ViewModel however it will not update.

Recipe.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="FitnessScript.Views.Recipes">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Please Enter Ingredients and Requirements!" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextType="Text" 
                Margin="0,20,0,0"
                FontSize="25"/>
            <Label Text="Enter Ingredients" Margin="5"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Ingredients"
                   Text="{Binding Ingredients}"
                   Placeholder="Ingredients"
                   PlaceholderColor="LightGray" />

            <Label Text="Enter Calories" Margin="5"/>
            <Entry x:Name="Calories"
                   Text="{Binding Calories}"
                   Placeholder="Calories"
                   PlaceholderColor="LightGray" />

            <Button x:Name="RecipeSearchBtn"
                    Text="Find Recipes"
                    Command="{Binding RequestRecipeCommand}" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="ProgressB"
                         Progress="{Binding ProgressValue}"
                         ProgressColor="Purple"
                         IsVisible="True"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Recipes.xmal.cs

```
namespace FitnessScript.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Recipes : ContentPage
    {
        RecipeSearchViewModel recipeSearchViewModel;
        public Recipes()
        {
            recipeSearchViewModel = new RecipeSearchViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = recipeSearchViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeSearchViewModel

```
namespace FitnessScript.ViewModels
{
    public class RecipeSearchViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private static readonly IRecipeService _recipeService = new RecipeService();
        private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;

        #region Getters/Setters 
        string _ingredients;
        public string Ingredients
        {
            get { return _ingredients; }
            set
            {
                _ingredients = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Ingredients");
            }
        }

        int _calories;
        public int Calories
        {
            get { return _calories; }
            set
            {
                _calories = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Calories");
            }
        }
        float _progressValue;
        public float ProgressValue
        {
            get { return _progressValue; }
            set
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ProgressValue");
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public RecipeSearchViewModel()
        {
            this.worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        }

        public Command RequestRecipeCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () => await RequestRecipe());
            }
        }

        private async Task RequestRecipe()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                { ProgressValue = 1; }
                );
            });
            List<string> ingredientsList = await _recipeService.GetRecipe(Ingredients, Calories);
            App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", $"{Ingredients}, {Calories}", "Close");
        }
    }
}
```

I Have tired many different alternatives, such as setting ProgressValue to Double and Decimal, forcing the UI thread, with and without adding a parameter to OnPropertyChange(). I've attempted background works too, just nothing sadly. 
I'm debugging using a S10+ via USB as I prefer it to emulation.

The overall aim is to press the RecipeSearchBtn, do the logic, and update the progress bar along with it, however for debugging purposes I just want to change the progress to 100% when the button command executes

Any help would be appreaciated, thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  You are not incrementally changing `ProgressValue` - you just set it to 1 and then call your service.  If you just want to indicate that something is happening to the user, use an ActivityIndicator.

Comment: Ah, I may have missed something then. Very new to Xamarin and most of the tutorials I've seen just set the Progress bind to 1. Also I have tried the Activity Indicator however similar issues, it never showed while debugging though my phone when setting the visibility ect to true through binding IsBool

Comment: ProgressBar has a value between 0 and 1 that represents the % completion of a task. It's designed to show incremental progress.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'll go back to attempting to get an ActivityInidcator to work. Do you have any idea as to why I couldnt get it working previously as described in my previous comment? Can supply the code haha. Appreciate the help

Comment: @GeorgeStrike Please take a look my reply below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also I have tried the Activity Indicator however similar issues, it never showed while debugging though my phone when setting the visibility ect to true through binding IsBool

About binding ActivityIndicator isvisible, I do one sample that you can take a look:

Please take a look the following code, ActivityIndicator display firstly, clicking button to load data, setting ActivityIndicator isVisible and IsRunning as false.

```
  <StackLayout>
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Command="{Binding command1}"
            Text="load data" />

        <ActivityIndicator
            HeightRequest="50"
            IsRunning="{Binding isvisible}"
            IsVisible="{Binding isvisible}"
            WidthRequest="50"
            Color="Red" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding students}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding age}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>


    </StackLayout>

 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new studentviewmodel();
    }
}

public class studentviewmodel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<studentmodel> students { get; set; }
    public Command command1 { get; set; }
    private bool _isvisible;
    public bool isvisible
    {
        get { return _isvisible; }
        set
        {
            _isvisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("isvisible");
        }
    }
    public studentviewmodel()
    {

        command1 = new Command(loaddata);
        isvisible = true;
        students = new ObservableCollection<studentmodel>();

    }

    private async void loaddata()
    {
        //call service to do other something.
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        students.Add(new studentmodel() { name = "cherry", age = 29 });
        students.Add(new studentmodel() { name = "barry", age = 30 });
        students.Add(new studentmodel() { name = "annine", age = 15 });  

        isvisible = false;

    }
}
public class studentmodel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, to notify data changed.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot:

[image]